# The variable input should store the value of input field, but it stores undefined instead

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please review below code.  **"The variable input should store the value of input field, but it stores undefined instead"**

```
var input = $("#input-item").val();
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add-item").click(function() {

    if(input !== "" || input !== null) {
        $("#ulTodo").append("<li " + "name=li" + count + ">" + input + "</li>");
        count += 1;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Because you have not posted HTML, where is <input type="text" id="input-item">, Please post HTML code too.

Comment: <input type="text" id="input-item" name="input-item" placeholder="add an item to the list...">

Answer (score 0):

Problem : variable `input` is `undefined`

> Solution :
>
> 1) You have assigned variable value out side click event,
>   it means has no value in the beginning
>
> 2) Apply `var input = $("#input-item").val();` in 
>   `$("#add-item").click()` event

Check below code :

```js
var count = 0;
        
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-item").click(function () {
        var input = $("#input-item").val();//input variable assigned in click event
        if (input !== "" || input !== null) {
            $("#ulTodo").append("<li " + "name=li" + count + ">" + input + "</li>");
            count += 1;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input-item" name="input-item" placeholder="add an item to the list...">
<button id="add-item">Add this item</button>

<p>Item list as below :</p>
<ul id="ulTodo">
    <li>this is item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Already solved it after rechecking the code, but thank you for the answer.